# Sum objects with same interface, but not the same

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a program to check the number of occurrences of a document based on rules set by me. With the help of regex, I check some fields, and if a particular field exists , I can count the number of occurrences of it, or I create a deeper scan. It's a little confusing, and I do not know exactly how to explain.

I 'm checking text files, but to reduce the complexity , I will use arrays.

I have the following array:

```
let strings = [
  'COMPANY: NAME  ID: 12',
  'COMPANY: NAME  ID: 12',
  'COMPANY: NAME  ID: 12',
  'COMPANY: NAME2 ID: 10'
];
```

And this is the desire output:

```
[
  {
    "NAME": {
      "12": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "NAME2": {
      "10": 1
    }
  }
]
```

My logic:

```js
'use strict';

let patterns = [
  {
    'pattern': 'COMPANY:\\s*?([\\w]+)',
    'modifier': ''
  },
  {
    'pattern': 'ID:\\s*?([\\d]+)',
    'modifier': ''
  }
];

let strings = [
  'COMPANY: NAME  ID: 12',
  'COMPANY: NAME  ID: 12',
  'COMPANY: NAME  ID: 12',
  'COMPANY: NAME2 ID: 10'
];

var SUPER = [];
var _data = {};

for (let string of strings) {

 let i      = 0;
 let length = patterns.length
  var root   = _data;

  for (i; i < length; i++) {

    let item   = patterns[i];

    let regex  = new RegExp(item.pattern, item.modifier);
    let result = regex.exec(string);


    if (i < patterns.length -1) {

     root = root[result[1]] = {};

    } else {
      root  = root[result[1]] = 1;





      SUPER.push(_data);
      _data = {};
    }
  }
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(SUPER, null ,2));
```

Now i have this gap, which i need check if the object already exists, and if so, i just increment the last item.

Any ideias or suggestions??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
// This (big_hash) is where we will store the output
// Sample output:
// {
//   NAME: {
//     "12": 3
//   },
//   NAME2: {
//     "10": 1
//   }
// }
let big_hash = {};

for (let string of strings){

  let pattern_matches = [];

  for (let pattern of patterns){
    let regex = new RegExp(pattern.pattern, pattern.modifier);
    pattern_matches[pattern_matches.length] = regex.exec(string);
  }

  // if all the patterns matched
  if( pattern_matches.every( match => match ) ){
    // separate logic for the last match, because its value is not a hash
    last_match = pattern_matches.pop();

    some_node = big_hash;
    for(let match of pattern_matches){
      let key = match[1];
      some_node[ key ] = some_node[ key ] || {};
      some_node = some_node[ key ];
    }

    // for the last level matching, the default value is 0, not {}
    some_node[ last_match ] = some_node[ last_match ] || 0;
    some_node[ last_match ] = some_node[ last_match ] + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u provide a functional example?? This isn't actually working.